# Quadratic equation?

Tags: quadratics

Say I have an equation, $\sqrt 2 x^2 - \sqrt 3 x + k = 0$, $k$ is a constant and there are 2 solutions $\sin \theta$ and $\cos\theta$ in the interval $0\le \theta \le \pi/2$.

What is the value of $k$?

How should I view this question? Equaling two equations where one is $f(x) = \sin\theta$ and another $f(x) = \cos\theta$? :p

It'd be great if someone could be of guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sqrt2x^2-\sqrt3x+k=0$$

We have $$\sin\theta+\cos\theta=\dfrac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt2}\  \ \ \ (1)$$

$$\sin\theta\cos\theta=\dfrac k{\sqrt2}\  \ \ \ (2)$$

Take the square of $(1)$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Ah..found the answer. So for (1) it's sum of solutions equals -b/a and (2) product of solutions c/a am I correct?

Comment: @cartmanbrahhhhh, See https://brilliant.org/wiki/vietas-formula/

Comment: Call it sum and product of roots. Sum of roots is $\frac{-b}{a}$ and product of roots is $\frac{c}{a}$